# Can "replete" be used as verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, adjectives, parts-of-speech

I thought that *replete* could be used as a verb meaning something like "refill" because of the other verbs sharing the same root ***plere***, such as *complete* or *deplete*, which are used as verbs without question. But I found in the dictionary that *replete* is actually only used as an adjective, meaning "filled."

Do sentences like these make no sense to you?

> Please replete the bowl.
>   The water was repleted in the pool.
>   She repletes my empty heart.

How come *replete* works only as an adjective?

Comment: Wiktionary gives the verbal intercategorial polyseme, without even flagging it as a rare usage. But it's a very rare usage.

Comment: Those sentences read perfectly to me (native English speaker), and I would not have questioned those uses of "replete".  I only found this post because I often google what I think are rarer usages to see what non-native speakers would see if they looked it up.  I think that "replete" will be verbed soon enough, if it is not already verbed.  Dictionaries lag usage since they describe it.

Comment: Although I’ve been reading daily for 65 years, I’ve never heard the word “replete” used as a verb until today. As a result, it sounded very very strange and wrong in an article I just read. If it starts being used more as a verb, I guess I’ll have to get used to it. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because we already have *[replenish](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/replenish)* for that purpose.

Comment: Hey! I voted you up.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I don’t understand why you are asking why.

Comment: Comment not question.

Comment: Interesting... I expected a verb-form of "to replete" to mean "to un-deplete" ("to mostly replenish from a state of mostly empty"), whereas I expect replenish to be capable of substituting "to top up", and in general to mean "to re-establish plentitude".  Thus I expected "to replenish" to apply both if the initial level were low or if it were merely "not plenty".

Comment: @EdwardNewell One such does exist, but it is orders of magnitude less frequently encountered.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to obsolete and rare meanings of the verb, the OED has

**replete** (v.)

> *transitive*. To fill again; to replenish.
>
> **1614**   A. Gorges tr. Lucan Pharsalia x. 433   The Torrid Zone with
> heates, Held them from doing of those feates, To see what springs
> warme Nyle **repleates**.
> ...
> **1998**   *People* (Nexis) 7 June 10   Some sweet Parisian music will
> provide gentle accompaniment to the serious business of **repleting**
> vital stocks of blood.

The OED assigns this verb to *[Frequency Band 3](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-frequency/)*:

> Band 3 contains words which occur between 0.01 and 0.1 times per
> million words in typical modern English usage. **These words are not
> commonly found in general text types like novels and newspapers, but
> at the same time they are not overly opaque or obscure.** Nouns include
> ebullition and merengue, and examples of adjectives are amortizable,
> prelapsarian, contumacious, agglutinative, quantized, argentiferous.
> In addition, adjectives include a marked number of very colloquial
> words, e.g. cutesy, dirt-cheap, teensy, badass, crackers. Verbs and
> adverbs diverge to opposite ends of the spectrum of use encompassed by
> this band. **Verbs tend to be either colloquial or technical, e.g.
> emote, mosey, josh, recapitalize.**

---

> After the excellent French cuisine **had repleted** our sundried
> bodies, *Barbara* again sallied forth, this time for the 2200 mile
> voyage direct to Mombasa, in comparatively peaceful Kenya. [*The
> Rudder*, Vol. 93, p.64](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Rudder/RXwqAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22had%20repleted%22&dq=%22had%20repleted%22&printsec=frontcover) (1997)

> *To fill* is ... in Hebrew, meaning "to fill" or "**to replete.**" [Abraham Park; *The Covenant of the Torch*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Covenant_of_the_Torch/goPQAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20replete%22%20means&pg=PT113&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> Once fluid administration **has repleted** the ECF, forced diuresis
> (with associated calcium loss) can be initiated with a loop diuretic.
> For this approach to be successful, normal kidney function is
> required. [M. Chisholm-Burns et al.; *Pharmacotherapy Principles &
> Practice*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pharmacotherapy_Principles_Practice/OdGjGH26yPoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22has%20repleted%22&dq=%22has%20repleted%22&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> The Afghans have always been famous fighters and almost every
> ambitious conqueror **has repleted** his armies with their valuable
> and liberal recruitment. [*Central Asia, Issues 14-17*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Central_Asia/bIJCAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22has%20repleted%22&dq=%22has%20repleted%22&printsec=frontcover) p.134
> (1984)

> Lipid deposition spreads outwards towards the glomerulosa and for a
> time the gland has an appearance which is the reverse of the normal in
> that the outer part of the fasciculata is without fat while the inner
> region **has repleted** its fat stores. [Ivor Mills; *Clinical Aspects
> of Adrenal Function*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Clinical_Aspects_of_Adrenal_Function/vSNsAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22has%20repleted%22&dq=%22has%20repleted%22&printsec=frontcover) (1964)

> So he proceeded to Europe **to replete** the exhausted treasury by
> means of a loan. [Arthur Scaife; *The War to Date (March 1, 1900)*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_War_to_Date_March_1_1900/mlwLAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20replete%22%20means&pg=PA35&printsec=frontcover)

> The Energy and Mines Minister said that throuch an ambitious drilling
> program the oil industry for the past two years **has repleted** its
> reserves, reversing a trend "of many years". [*Carib-Latin energy
> Consultant*, Vols. 5-6, p.56](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Carib_Latin_Energy_Consultant/b5tFAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22has%20repleted%22&dq=%22has%20repleted%22&printsec=frontcover) (1981)

> Mill men have been unable to understand the weakness of a week ago
> because their stocks were broken and it would have been impossible for
> them **to have repleted** a general yard stock. [*The Southern
> Lumberman*, p.20](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Southern_Lumberman/8ChHAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22and%20it%20would%20have%20been%20impossible%22) (1917)

> The effectiveness of "reduced iron" in **repleting** the hemoglobin of
> anemic rats or chicks was studied in a collaborative experiment among
> eight American and Canadian laboratories (105). [*Hearing Draft:
> Tentative Evaluation of the Health Aspects of ...*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hearing_Draft/DNBFAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22repleting%22&dq=%22repleting%22&printsec=frontcover) (1979)

> Hypopituitarism is currently treated with pharmacotherapy directed at
> **repleting** the deficient hormones. ACTH deficiency is **repleted** with administration of hydrocortisone daily; ... TSH deficiency is
> **repleted** with thyroid hormone replacement. Gonadotropin deficiency is **repleted** using sex steroid replacement ... Deficiency in vasopressin may be **repleted** with
> synthetic analogues. [N. Bhattacharya and P. Stubblefield; *Human
> Fetal Tissue Transplantation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Human_Fetal_Tissue_Transplantation/FbE_AAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=repleted&pg=PA178&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

> Nietzsche **will replete** this silence with the will of life, will
> that turns its back both on the State and other human and can only
> love itself.  [J.Brzeziński et al.; *The Courage of Doing
> Philosopy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Courage_of_Doing_Philosophy/l2mbxJ0fUdUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22will%20replete%22&pg=PA409&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> Psychoanalysis and Marxism were also good candidates to fill the
> twentieth-century meaning vacuum, the former by focusing the person on
> the self in order **to replete** the emptiness, the latter by focusing
> on society. [Emmy van Deurzen; *Everyday Mysteries: A Handbook of
> Existential Psychotherapy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Everyday_Mysteries/PL6NAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20replete%22%20means&pg=PA170&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> The body stores of a nutrient can sometimes be depleted by feeding an
> animal a diet deficient in that nutrient. The rate at which a food
> **can replete** the lost body store is another approach to food evaluation using the whole animal. [D. Gruenwedel and J. Whitaker
> (eds.); *Food Analysis*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Food_Analysis/Cugtm3tTXC8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22can%20replete%22&pg=PA9&printsec=frontcover) (1985)

Comment: Unarguably the correct and correctly researched answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *replenish* would be the same thing as *replete*, if replete was used as a verb. According to the dictionary definitions I read, replete means to be stuffed to the point of not wanting more. That over-abundance is not implied in replenish. And stuffed isn't always the word you want.